# codeigniter project, unable to send mails to hotmail mail ids

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer, hotmail

**Mail Sending Issue**

codeigniter mail sending working fine for gmail, yahoo, rediff etc.

only **codeigniter mail sending is not working during hotmail**.

I checked all hotmail a/c settings, even from-mail-id added into safe-mail-list. Though hotmail not receiving mails.

**My Mail Config Code:**

```
....
....
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['smtp_host'] = "localhost";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = TRUE;
$config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
$config['newline']  = '\r\n';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this -> load -> library('email');
....
....
```

Even I changed..

```
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
```

To..

```
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
```

Though its not working..

please suggest me changes to receive emails to hotmail ids also

Comment: That's probably happening because of hotmail spam filters.

Comment: but if I send it directly through mail login.. then mail sending is working. then why not through the coding

Comment: Is it a paid Hotmail account? I faced same problem with gmail paid account. they are applying additional spam filters for premium account to protect from spam email generated by servers.